# How to properly begin with Kotlin.js

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js

I am fairly new to the world of web development and was looking resources to get started. I had prior knowledge of Kotlin and I learned that I can use Kotlin.js to build my webApps/website. I tried looking for some guides/tutorials on the web to find something where I could learn web development with Kotlin.js but I couldn't find anything beginner friendly.
Is there any resources which will help in getting started with Kotlin.js or will I have to learn JS first? And if there is do I need to learn HTML/CSS first? 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Kotlin/JS is a technology that heavily interoperates with and relies on the web ecosystem, having knowledge around those technologies is definitely beneficial.

If you want to write applications with Kotlin/JS that run in the browser, you need an understanding of what makes up your site: While Kotlin/JS provides abstractions over concepts like [HTML](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html) and CSS (or corresponding frameworks like [styled-components](http://kotlin-styled)), allows you to use JavaScript packages, and more – **these abstractions still require you to understand the basics of the underlying concepts**.

With a basic understanding of HTML and CSS, you should be able to follow the steps outlined in the tutorials section on the [official Kotlin website](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/setting-up.html).

For a more interactive start into Kotlin/JS as a technology, which comes with detailed explanations, includes official sample projects, and uses real-world frameworks, the [hands-on section](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/01_Introduction) on the Kotlin website can teach you about how to build [React](https://reactjs.org/) + Kotlin/JS applications.

*[Source: I work as a Developer Advocate for Kotlin/JS at JetBrains]*

Comment: How does one get started integrating a UI framework like bootstrap / microsoft fast / material ?